Using a model via python script
I may not understand complicated suggestions and answers, but it's for my university, and I don't have time to learn basics.
I'm trying to use a model that I created by using GTZAN DATASET - Music Genre Classicification (https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/andradaolteanu/gtzan-dataset-music-genre-classification)
Model has a high accuracy, but I don't get satisfying outputs. I don't know how much info is needed, but I feel like I am making a mistake in the script that I use. Here is the script.
import tensorflow as tf
import librosa
import numpy as np

# Load the pre-trained model
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('C:/Users/VOLKAN/Desktop/SonProject/model.keras')

# Define the genres (assuming you have a fixed list of genres the model predicts)
genres = ['Blues', 'Classical', 'Country', 'Disco', 'Hip-hop', 'Jazz', 'Metal', 'Pop', 'Reggae', 'Rock']  # Replace with actual genre names

def extract_features(file_path):
    y, sr = librosa.load(file_path, duration=30)
    mfccs = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=y, sr=sr, n_mfcc=58)
    mfccs = np.mean(mfccs.T, axis=0)
    features = mfccs[np.newaxis, ...]
    return features



def predict_genre(file_path):
    features = extract_features(file_path)
    predictions = model.predict(features)
    genre_index = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)[0]
    return genres[genre_index]

# Example usage
audio_file = 'C:/Users/VOLKAN/Desktop/Data/genres_original/classical/classical.00059.wav'  # Replace with your audio file path
predicted_genre = predict_genre(audio_file)
print(f'The predicted genre is: {predicted_genre}')


`
In model, I used CNN. Model has a .keras extension.
